# How can I handle class instantiation dynamically

Tags: typescript, generics

I dont have much experience with typescript and could do with some help dynamically handling object initialisation:

I have a series of classes which all have a parameters sub class in the following structure:

```
export class MainClass1 {
     getParameters(): MainClass1.Parameters | undefined;
     setParameters(value?: MainClass1.Parameters): void;
}

export namespace MainClass1 {
    export class Parameters{
    }
}

export class MainClass2 {
     getParameters(): MainClass2.Parameters | undefined;
     setParameters(value?: MainClass2.Parameters): void;
}

export namespace MainClass2 {
    export class Parameters{
    }
}
```

The above is code i'm consuming so I cannot edit the class constructor but what I need to do is go from a string. e.g 'MainClass1' to return an instantiated Mainclass1 with an instantiated MainClass1.Parameters object, so right now I have code for each class like the following:

```
case 'MainClass1':
    let mc1 : Lib.MainClass1 = new Lib.MainClass1();
    let mc1Params : Lib.MainClass1.Parameters = new Lib.MainClass1.Parameters();
    mc1.setParameters(mc1Params);
    return mc1;
```

the return type of the above is an interface like this:

```
export interface GenericMainClass {
    getParameters() : any;
    getId(): string;
    setId(value: string): void;
    getClassName(): string;
    getValue(): Lib.Value | undefined;
    setValue(value?: Lib.Value): void;
}
```

As I say what i would ideally like is to be able to handle this instantiation dynamically. Can anyone show me how to instantiate these classes as described from a string name, is this possible and then how I should present a generic wrapper around setParameters, i hoped something like `setParameters<T>(value? : T) : void;` on the interface might work, but typescript complains about incompatible types when I try that.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 100% valid way to handle it in Typescript, but you can try semi-hacky way:

```js
function newClass<TClass extends Lib.GenericMainClass>(name: "Class1" | "Class2"): TClass {
    const Class = Lib[name];
    const instance = new Lib[name]() as any as TClass;
    const parameters = new Lib[name].Parameters();
    instance.setParameters(parameters);
    return instance;
}

const newInstanceOfClass1 = newClass("Class1");
const newInstanceOfClass2 = newClass("Class2");

const newInstanceOfClass1Typed = newClass<Lib.Class1>("Class1");
const newInstanceOfClass2Typed = newClass<Lib.Class2>("Class2");
```

Here is url to [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20module%20Lib%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20type%20Value%20%3D%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20GenericMainClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20getParameters()%20%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20getId()%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20setId(value%3A%20string)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20getClassName()%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20getValue()%3A%20Value%20%7C%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20setValue(value%3F%3A%20Value)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20GenericClass%20implements%20GenericMainClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20getParameters()%20%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20getId()%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20setId(value%3A%20string)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20getClassName()%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20getValue()%3A%20Value%20%7C%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20setValue(value%3F%3A%20Value)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20Class1%20extends%20GenericClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20setParameters(value%3F%3A%20Class1.Parameters)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20namespace%20Class1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20export%20class%20Parameters%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20Class2%20extends%20GenericClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20setParameters(value%3F%3A%20Class2.Parameters)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20namespace%20Class2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20export%20class%20Parameters%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20newClass%3CTClass%20extends%20Lib.GenericMainClass%3E(name%3A%20%22Class1%22%20%7C%20%22Class2%22)%3A%20TClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20Class%20%3D%20Lib%5Bname%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20instance%20%3D%20new%20Lib%5Bname%5D()%20as%20any%20as%20TClass%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20parameters%20%3D%20new%20Lib%5Bname%5D.Parameters()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20instance.setParameters(parameters)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20instance%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20newInstanceOfClass1%20%3D%20newClass(%22Class1%22)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20newInstanceOfClass2%20%3D%20newClass(%22Class2%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20newInstanceOfClass1Typed%20%3D%20newClass%3CLib.Class1%3E(%22Class1%22)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20newInstanceOfClass2Typed%20%3D%20newClass%3CLib.Class2%3E(%22Class2%22)%3B%0D%0A)

**Explanation:**

- `Lib` is a usual JS object here, and you can still refer to it's keys same as in usual JS.
- `as any as TClass` is a hack, that forces TypeScript to cast unknown type to what you need to.
- `<TClass extends ...>` is a Generic type, that used inside the `newClass` function and can be defined when you call the `newClass` function like this: `newClass<MyType>`

**Without having it defined:**

`const newInstanceOfClass1 = newClass("Class1");`

it will be typeof `Lib.GenericMainClass`

**With having it defined:**

`const newInstanceOfClass1Typed = newClass<Lib.Class1>("Class1");`

it will be typeof `Lib.Class1`

So you are free to choose, if you need `GenericMainClass` or particular class when using `newClass`

**Notes:**

If you want to have absolutely any name of the class, then define `newClass` function like this:

`function newClass<TClass extends Lib.GenericMainClass>(name: string): TClass {
...`

If you still want to have control all possible class names, then you can use enum:

```js
enum ClassNames {
   Class1: "Class1",
   Class2: "Class2",
   ...
}
function newClass<TClass extends Lib.GenericMainClass>(name: ClassNames): TClass {
...
```